# How to display OpenCV camera stream in the same window as another file?

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I have been trying to use OpenCV to display my camera stream in the same window as another (GUI) window. However, the **imshow()** method opens its own window. Is there another way to do this so that it displays in the same window as my GUI?

Comment: Where did the other window come from? How do you expect OpenCV to know of its existence?

Comment: `imshow` and the rest of the HighGUI stuff is meant for convenience when prototyping. Beyond that, you need to write your own code to do the visualization (depends on framework you use, which you failed to mention) -- in general it's rather trivial, and there are multiple relevant posts here about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the GUI you're talking about is Tkinter, but opencv's cv.imshow is just playing frame.I don't think it's necessary to use GUI to show frame.Because cv2.imshow is good at handling.